# MermaidJS command not working from the paclet

Tags: packages, windows, command-line

I have installed the mermaid command line package and added it to the environment variable `Path` and it is accessible from the command line:

[image]

But the following command is not working:

```
PacletInstall["AntonAntonov/MermaidJS"]
Needs["AntonAntonov`MermaidJS`"]
MermaidJS["
graph TD
    WL --> |ZMQ|Python --> |ZMQ|WL
"]
```

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

---

I think it by default it uses the `"Prolog" -> "source ~/.zshrc"` which is a `Linux` command, maybe I need to use a different `"Prolog"` for `Windows`?

```
MermaidJS["
graph TD
    WL --> |ZMQ|Python --> |ZMQ|WL
","Prolog" -> "source ~/.zshrc"]
```